# How to generate random sequence of numbers between a given range in c#

Tags: c#

I want to generate a random number of sequences in a specified range on the timer tick event. The difference between the first and next random number should be 0.5 and continues the pattern.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(500);
    aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Tick);
    aTimer.AutoReset = true;

}

Random random = new Random();

private void timer_Tick(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Dispatcher.Invoke(() => CreatePoint(random.Next(0, 5), random.Next(0, 5)));
}
```

I am able to generate the random numbers, but how do I specify the distance between two random numbers?

Comment: Store the first number in a variable, then use that in the parameters to generate the second (not *just* that value of course).

Comment: Does the difference MUST be 0.5 or be not more than 0.5 ? By that i mean if the generated number is 1 does the next number must be either 0.5 or 1.5 OR can it be 0.9 but it can't be 1.6 ?

Comment: Yes. It can be 0.5 to .0.9 and  if its generate a number 1 so next number should be 1.5 or 0.5 and continues

Comment: The only thing that's random here is the direction each number is from the previous.  Just generate a random number between 0 and 1, and if it's less than 0.5, subtract 0.5 from the previous number; else, add 0.5.

Comment: I am not clear on what the requirements are.

Comment: Your definition of the conditions and constraints of the random sequence you desire is not clear.  Please describe in **much more detail** exactly what kind of random sequence you want.  I suggest providing the generator rules, and a few examples of sequences along with a written explanation.  Right now it's just too unclear what you're asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a random to generate a value of -0.5 to 0.5 and add it to previous value.
By reusing a portion of your code here's a example modification you can do

```
Random random = new Random();
double currentX = 0d;
double currentY = 0d;

private void timer_Tick(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{       
    // add the random modifier between -0.5 and 0.5 to each x/y values
    currentX += GetRandomModifier();
    currentY += GetRandomModifier();
}

private double GetRandomModifier()
{
    // generate a number between -0.5 and 0.5
    return random.Next(-50, 50) / 100d;
}
```

Comment: `random.NextDouble()` generates a double between `0.0` and `1.0`.

Comment: @Amy yes but not what i used. I used the `int` because of the inclusive